# Processing Response from URL Call

Tags: paypal, xpages

I am trying to simply submit a url and get the response back so I can read it and do other actions, in JavaScript or LotusScript.  What is the simplest/best way to do this?

Fyi, the reason I'm trying to do this is to submit order information to PayPal for processing, and process their response.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you want the backend to make the URL call? I would agree with Kristian that you want to do that in the client, but that depends on your application flow.

On the server: LotusScript can't reach out to URLs. With SSJS you leverage on the HTTPClient to do that. So the best is to make a bean for that. While I would not suggest to use the LS code here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8BQNWN - you can use the Java class to get some ideas how to build the bean.

Would that work for you?

Comment: The access to the PayPal API is requiried to run in the backend because you have to log in with the credentials of your online shop. To do a http request in SSJS it is the easiest to use java.net.HttpURLConnection.

Comment: the Apache http client makes it even easier - handling cookies, redirects etc

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should perform the form submission via ajax and not submit the page itself along with the form data. That way you can parse the response and play with it.

Are you you using jquery? if so, try out the $.ajax() method. You have a lot of power to do what you want if you use something like that.